# How to strip away markup and paste only plain text into content editable field?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Here is playground: http://jsfiddle.net/n6W27/1/

try to Ctrl+A Ctrl+C Ctrl+V and see that contenteditable node was duplicated(at least for me in firefox).
The original question is how could I force only plain-text input into contenteditable block?
And the derived question is "Why the !@#$ node duplicated next to original one?"

**Edit1:** There is only one block in this demo, so I put caret inside editable block and then select all, copy, and paste

**Edit2:** result screenshot [image]

Comment: this behavior driving me crazy, it's absolutely not trivial why browser creates content NEXT to contenteditable node.

Comment: Please provide instructions. What exactly are you copying, and pasting? Where is the caret?

Comment: 14.0.1, Ill make some screens now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, change the element type to DIV. That will clear your issue.

```
<div class="edit" contenteditable>ABC</div>
```

If you don't want your field to be block-level, set the display property to "inline-block":

```
.edit {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/n6W27/2/